# Dynamic HTML using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

In an attempt to make my code more encapsulated, and thus easier to read, I've opted to use echo statements to fill in redundant sections across my web application's webpages. For example, all of my pages have the same nav-bar, footer, and header(for the most part). I've implemented a way to "inject" html fragments dynamically, much like jQuery can do. A snippet of my index page looks something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<?php
    // START Head.
    echo "<head>";
        // Inject Head here.
        echo $page_content['head'];
    echo "</head>";
    // END Head.
    // START Body.
    echo "<body>";
        // Inject Navbar here.
        echo $page_content['navbar'];
        // START Div{.container}.
        echo "<div class=\"container\">";
            // Inject Search Bar here.
            echo $page_content['searchbar'];
            // Inject Footer content here.
            echo $page_content['footer'];
        echo "</div>";
        // END Div{.container}.
    echo "</body>";
    // END Body.
?>
```

The `$page_content` variable hold all the fragments.

What are the benefits? What are the drawbacks? Are there any concepts I am overlooking here in an attempt to make my code more concise?

Comment: What you're looking for/trying to reinvent is [PHP Templating](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=PHP+Templating) - you should read up on it and how to do it effectively.

Comment: @Darren this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally mixing markup and PHP is considered bad practice, and makes maintenance a nightmare. Also should the need arise, it is harder for the work to be divided between a front-end developer and you. Consider using an off-the-shelf templating engine instead like Twig (among others) as this allows you to achieve what you are trying to do more elegantly:

```
<head>
  {{ $page_content['head'] }}
</head>
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/